# How to copy selected item style to another item in Solid Edge?

Tags: vb.net

I'm developing a macro for Solid Edge which is stores values of things like font size, width etc. and applies them to another object. Both functions are executable by button click. First button is saving the property values and second applies them to another object. The problem is that I have no clue which methods or functions should I use to store the values.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim solidedge As SolidEdge.Framework.Interop.Application
    Dim line As SolidEdge.Framework.Interop.SelectSet
    Dim item As SolidEdge.FrameworkSupport.Interop.Line2d
    Dim style As SolidEdge.FrameworkSupport.Interop.GeometryStyle2d
    Dim breite As Double
    Dim dashname As String
    Dim autophase As Boolean
    Dim dashgapcount As Integer
    Dim dashstrokepercent As Double
    Dim color As Integer
    Dim linearname As String
    Dim units As Integer

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        solidedge = GetObject(, "SolidEdge.Application")
        line = solidedge.ActiveSelectSet
        item = line.Item(1)
        style = item.Style
        breite = style.Width
        autophase = style.AutoPhase
        dashgapcount = style.DashGapCount
        dashstrokepercent = style.DashStrokePercent
        color = style.LinearColor
        linearname = style.LinearName
        units = style.Units
        dashname = style.DashName
    End Sub
End Class
```

*Example:* I want make the black line look like the pink line by copying format:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "store the values?" Are you trying to save the data to disk? Do you intend to move it from computer to computer, or simply retrieve it later?

Comment: I have already this values on my item1 ( the selected one ). http://gyazo.com/312a550e342f5f08946ecef1d890af32  Now i just want to save those values, and take them on other selected object.

Comment: You'll have to be more clear on what you're asking. Your question says, _i have no clue which methods or functions should i use to store the values_, but you do not say where or how you want to store them, nor what you intend to do with them. Are you now trying to **apply** these values to another object in the external program?

Comment: Okey, i will try to explain it again, I have two lines (objects) http://gyazo.com/e0f4c84a42b9c3f894a4797cc9518a34 (the pink one is the selected - item1) and it has his width, long etc. I want now, to store those values of width, long etc. from the pink one and to transfer them on the second one ( black one ). What would you recommend me , how to store this, so the program will know, which values have been saved.

Comment: It should be working like button1- is saving the values of selected line and button2- is executing them on the other selected object (in this case the smaller one to make this like pink one).

Comment: I believe this is what you are looking for: [Match Properties](http://www.surfandcode.in/2014/09/match-properties-for-solid-edge-part-1.html)  You can download source code on last step.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Solid Edge, but based on the code you posted, you could try something like this:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    solidedge = GetObject(, "SolidEdge.Application")
    line = solidedge.ActiveSelectSet
    item = line.Item(2)
    item.Style = style
End Sub
```

Comment: The problem is that i can have only one selected object, and every selected object is the item1.

Comment: That's as far as I can help you by guessing. Perhaps you should consult the [documentation](http://www.plm.automation.siemens.com/zh_cn/Images/Solid_Edge_API_tcm78-125829.pdf).